# How to redirect HTTP request based on URL parameter?

Tags: nginx, tomcat, jetty

We are running two jetty containers in different host(Host-P, Host-Q). One of the container is deployed with few applications(App-A,App-B,App-C). Another container which is also having few applications(App-X,App-Y,App-Z).

```
Host-P => App-A,App-B,App-C
Host-Q => App-X,App-Y,App-Z
```

**myapp.test.com**  is the primary host accessible by web client. My web client is aware of the application which needs to invoke. I am passing this app type in URL param . The URL will be like

```
http://myapp.test.com/?=appType=App-A
http://myapp.test.com/?=appType=App-B

http://myapp.test.com/?=appType=App-Y
http://myapp.test.com/?=appType=App-X
```

Where I need to configure the routing logic based on URL param. Can I have tomcat/nginx running in **myapp.test.com** host that will do only routing? Which configuration file I need to lookup?

Answer (score 2):

If the query parameter refers to a container that you can address directly, you can just pass that to `proxy_pass` directly, e.g.:

```
        proxy_pass http://$arg_appType;
```

But that's using untrusted input and is also a massive security hole. Consider `?appType=www.google.com`. I show this as an example of what *not* to do.

---

Instead, use a [`map`](https://nginx.org/r/map) to map query parameters to destinations:

```
map $arg_appType $destination {
    App-A http://container1:8443;
    App-B http://container2:5000;
    App-X http://container24:9001;
    App-Y https://some.remote.host;
}
```

Now you can `proxy_pass` directly to it.

```
         proxy_pass $destination;
```

But you should also intercept the situation in which an unknown or no `appType` was given.

```
    if ($destination = "") {
        return 403;    # or do something else appropriate
    }
```

If you have a specific container to handle that scenario, you can use `default` in the `map` to send to it instead.

```
map $arg_appType $destination {
    ....
    default http://error-handler-container:8000;
}
```